# How can I completely integration of video conferencing and screen sharing?

Tags: video-conferencing, desktop-sharing

Is there any screen sharing and video conferencing software that can be integrated into a community type of website, where users can use it to communicate together without outside branding?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Weemo (docs.weemo.com). We provide a complete set of JS APIs and SDKs to add video conferencing and screen sharing into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution is to use https://appear.in/ who allows both conference call (free up to 8 users) and screen sharing (actually the *sharer* must be using chrome).

Checking their [faq](https://appear.in/information/faq) you can find out how to integrate "statics" rooms in your website just using an iframe or using the javascript SDK.

You can find more information here: https://developer.appear.in/